# Three column layout with an auto-width center column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 3 columns layout, where structure should be main, left column, right column. The main column is auto-width to fill rest of page.

Unfortunately I cannot change the HTML, which is currently like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**Yes: That means I cannot change the order of divs.**

I've found some solutions, one of these is by using `display: table-cell`, but there is issue when using `float`. Second solutions is layout by using flexbox, it is pretty good solution, but I cannot use it because of IE9 where this CSS style isn't supported.

Just to restate the aim: My need is to have left and right with fixed width, and main will fill rest of free space.

<---250px--><----------------auto-width-------------><---200px--->
<---Left-----><------------------main------------------><---right----->

Have anyone any solutions for this in pure CSS without any JavaScript?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that the divs cannot be rearranged (this was not stated in the original question and was only revealed in the comments).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. A simple CSS solution. Remember you should always clear your floats.

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.main, .left, .right {
    min-height: 250px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;    
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;    
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.main {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/18rvc23q/

Comment: Old school. <3 No fancy CSS12 wizardy necessary. This is how you know someone has been doing stuff for a long enough time. Probably also worshipped the _One True Layout_ somewhere along the way.

Comment: This seems as good solution, but I need to get <div class="main"> as the first child of wrap.

Comment: @MartinRohan You can't expect to style a webpage without *some* control over the semantic content, otherwise you'll need a JS solution.

Comment: @MartinRohan I have a solution that keeps element order.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**The better (but unsupported in IE9-) way**

```
.wrap {
    display:flex;
}

.left {
    flex-basis:250px;
}

.right {
    flex-basis:200px;
}

.main {
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

**The somewhat hackier, but supported in IE9 (but not IE8- or certain mobile browsers) way**

```
.wrap {
    display:block;
}

.left {
    width:250px;
}

.right {
    width:200px;
}

.main {
    width:calc(100% - 450px);
}
```

**UPDATE**: if you wanted to dynamically add / remove columns, just add a few extra classes in your CSS file:

```
.main.no-left {
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
}

.main.no-right {
    width:calc(100% - 250px);
}

.main.no-left.no-right {
    width:100%;
}
```

And apply the classes dynamically via JS as needed. Anything else requires a JS solution that actually sets the width as an inline style, or makes use of `position:absolute;`, which can get real hacky, real fast.

Comment: Browser compatibility for: [Flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), [Calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: I upvoted this, but there's actually a pure CSS solution that works in any browser. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28900500/199700

Comment: As I said, need support also for IE9 so flex i cannot use and calc is good solution, but i forgot to say that auto-width  was meant to fill page event if I remove one of the side column, than calc also cannot be used.

Comment: @PlantTheldea is my absolute positioned solution hacky?

Comment: @hungerstar - yup ... i could list it out, but i imagine it would start a flame-off, which i am uninterested in. i promise i was not one of your downvotes, however, i never downvote one questions ive answered in.

Comment: @MartinRohan -> by remove the column, i assume you remove it by JS? because there is an easy solution for that if so, you just add a class to `.main` to change the `calc()` components as needed. i've updated my answer to show the CSS for that.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I'm not going to start a flame war, I'm just not seeing how it is hacky. I would honestly like some feedback.

Comment: @hungerstar - Because it has a severe level of inflexibility, as you need to explicitly declare the widths for `.left` and `.right`, as well as the margins for `.main` to be equal. It limits the applicability for this solution to a single use case, which makes maintenance of things a mess. My `.calc()` solution is only slightly less hacky because it does not require additional declaration outside of `width`, but I described it as hacky because it has a single use-case and is therefore not a good practice. (btw, this is why flexbox is so highly revered).

Comment: @PlantTheIdea for sure it's a bit inflexible and requires multiple points to be adjusted, no doubt there. Wouldn't you agree though the OP's requirements tend to handcuff just about any solution? Thanks for the feedback, it aligned with known issues (which I was aware of) vs me just completely missing the point in some way!

Comment: @hungerstar - agreed, the restrictions are heavy, borderline ludicrous. considering these restrictions, i feel completely certain in saying that no solution can be anything but hacky haha.

Answer (score 2):

You could try floating the sidebars to the left and right respectively, and then applying some padding to the `.main` div to keep it from overlapping them.

```
<style>
.left {float: left; width: 250px;}
.right {float: right; width: 200px;}
.main {padding: 0 200px 0 250px;}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ofqkLmw/

Note that in this markup I've moved the `main` div to be the last child of `wrap`.

Also note that you can just as well use margin instead of padding - if you don't want the border and background to overlap the sidebars, then margin is the way to go.

Comment: What is the padding for? http://jsfiddle.net/z6o8yvzw/ The only problem is that you're not clearing your floats.

Comment: @Chuck It prevents text in `main` from appearing directly below the sidebars - try adding a few lines of text and removing the padding, and see what happens.

Comment: Good point. I guess it's down to how the OP is handling the heights of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mix of left and right margin on `.main` and then absolute position the `.left` and `.right` columns.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    margin: 0 100px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
.left,
.right {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/1u9gzyh6/

Comment: I think it's a terrible idea to use absolutely positioned elements in your layout -- but given the restrictions from the OP, this is actually a pretty decent solution.

Comment: @Chuck I normally would not do this myself and use an approach using floats as you have done if there was more flexibility in the markup. If this was an independent module within a page (but same restrictions) vs page layout, would you still consider it terrible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem:

```css
.main, .left, .right {
    height: 250px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -300px; // negative width of main   
}

.right {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 50px; // width of left
}

.main {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px; // width of left
}

.wrap:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="main">Main</div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to get order of columns left-main-right not main-left-right as your solutions do

Comment: You mean main-left-right, according to your post, Martin.

Comment: I mean main-left-right html structure but to display as left-main-right

Comment: @TimOsadchiy The OP needs the left and right columns to be fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

```
<style>
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
div.main-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.left-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
div.left-col {
    float: left;
    width: 200px; /*change to what value you desire*/
    background-color: #5446EB;
    height: 400px;
}
div.main-col {
    background-color: #DDEB46;
    height: 400px;
}

div.right-col {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;   /*change to what value you desire*/
    background-color: #EB838D;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="left-wrapper">
        <div class="left-col">
            insert content of the left col here
        </div>
        <div class="main-col">
            insert content of the main col here.  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        insert content of the right col here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed the order of elements, OP would like `.main` to be the first element inside of `.wrap`.